# How to prevent Putty from closing the session automatically?

Tags: windows-8.1, putty

While using putty, sometimes I enter the wrong username for a session and it returns the error as shown in the image below.

[image]

Once I click on 'OK', the session immediately closes, which is annoying.
How to set the session to stay on the screen, even if have entered a wrong username? (It will be helpful to restart the session and enter the correct username, rather than launching it from the beginning)

Comment: Configuration - Session - Close window on exit = Never ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the solution! @Akina